# Return to previous fragment in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm coding a navigation drawer on an Android app. Every time I push my first fragment I go to my Activity 1, and when I push the back button I return to my First Fragment which is my Default Fragment, so that is OK. But when I go to my Second Fragment I go to a new Activity (Activity2) but when I press the back button I return to my first fragment (like in the First Activity) BUT I want to return to my SECOND FRAGMENT.

Any help? [Here is an image how I want it to works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsHnO.jpg)

Comment: You may have to save which fragment was last shown, and load it when you return to activity1.

Comment: Sorry for bothering but how I can do that? I'm new in programming.

Comment: This is probably what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133600/set-initial-fragment-on-startup

Comment: It is not, but thanks.

Comment: only inflate, when `savedInstanceState == null` ...this means, at first load (else you most likely would inflate it again, which causes the situation, as you describe it).

Answer (score 0):

The Best Answer for this was already given @
[Programmatically go back to the previous fragment in the backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863572/programmatically-go-back-to-the-previous-fragment-in-the-backstack)

For more detail about fragment backstack follow the link given in answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863743/9917175